# Nodejs: Async job queue processing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, queue, jobs

I am working in nodejs with express for a web app that communicates with mongodb frequently. Currently I running production with my own job queue system that only begins processing a job once the previous job has been completed (an approach that seems to be taken by [kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue)).

To me, this seems wildly inefficient, I was hoping for a more asynchronous job queue, so I am looking for some advice as to how other nodejs developers queue their jobs and structure their processing.

One of my ideas is to process any jobs that are received immediately and return the resulting data in the order of addition.

Also to be considered: currently each user has their own independent job queue instance, is this normal practice? Is there any reason why this should not be the case? (ie, all users send jobs to one universal queue?)

Any comments/advice are appreciated.

Comment: More infos needed. In nodejs you better program everything with I/O async with callbacks. (Its actually hard not to...). Do you have a code example?

Comment: Here is the code of my current job queue system: https://gist.github.com/IyadAssaf/8655039 . A usage script is included to show how it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you build your own queue system? You did quite a lot of work to serialize a async queue with `addLocalJob`.

Why don't you just do something like

`on('request', function(req, res) { queryDB(parameter, function(result) { res.send(result) })`

? Full parallel access, no throttle, no (async) waiting.
If you really want to do it "by hand" in your own code, why not execute the first n elements of your `trafficQueue` instead of only the first?

If you want to throttle the DB - two ways:

- use a library like `async` and the function `parallelLimit`
- connect to your mongodb with http(s) and use the node-build-in `http.globalAgent.maxSockets`.

Hope this helps.